# Vercel - Deploy Flask Backend + React Frontend

Tags: reactjs, flask, deployment, vercel

I have a webapp that has React frontend with a Flask backend. I want to deploy this application onto a tool called Vercel. Can someone point me to an example tutorial/setup/example Github Repository that accomplishes this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't deploy the Flask back-end on Vercel. I am not familiar with Flask, but I checked right now and you can deploy your Flask back-end server on [railway.app](https://railway.app). Then hit from your front-end that you can deploy on Vercel.

Comment: Do you by any chance have an example I can refer to? Is railway.app free?

Comment: @karkirsubu  Unfortunately, I don't, but the Railway platform is pretty intuitive. Just select the GitHub repo where your server code is and deploy it. Yes, they have a free tier.

Comment: thanks. I was able to get railway deploy to work. just a bit of configuration needed to be done.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this out as well, even though Flask usage is technically "documented" in the [official docs](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#advanced-usage/advanced-python-usage/web-server-gateway-interface). You need something like this:

```
your_app_root/
└── api/
    ├── function1/
    │   └── index.py
    ├── function2/
    │   └── index.py
    └── index.py
```

```
#!index.py
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def catch_all(path):
    # Everything above this line should look the same for each 
    # index.py. Modify lines below this to have different logic
    # for different routes.
    return Response(
        "<h1>Flask</h1><p>You visited: /%s</p>" % (path), mimetype="text/html"
    )
```

Basically, each function is going to be a separate Flask app. So you cannot do any routes within the Flask api with @app.route. It needs to all be folder based because Vercel is doing the routing.